# NuxtImage returning 404

Tags: javascript, image, optimization, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I've installed NuxtImage in my Nuxt3 project. According to the docs (https://image.nuxt.com/get-started/installation), I should be able to just swap out an `img` element with the `NuxtImage` component like so:

Before:

```
<img src="_nuxt/assets/img/my-image.jpg" />
```

After:

```
<NuxtImg src="_nuxt/assets/img/my-image.jpg" />
```

The `img` tag works as expected, but the `NuxtImg` component returns a 404:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_ipx/_/_nuxt/assets/img/my-image.jpg 404 (IPX_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
```

Eh?

Comment: Did you have a look into the documentation? Probably you need to configure the ipx provider. Or the base url… Where does the _Nuxt folder come from?

Comment: Yeah. It says, "Nuxt Image comes with a preconfigured instance of unjs/ipx. An open source, self-hosted image optimizer based on lovell/sharp." However, after looking deeper into the docs, I found that the service assumes a public image directory. Thant was my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `nuxt.config`:

```
  image: {
    dir: 'assets/img'
  },
```

(The default behavior was to look for images in the public directory, which as was the problem.)

Then this works:

```
<NuxtImg src="/my-image.jpg" />
```